# Custom tiles responding according to size

Tags: angularjs, html, css

So I have created these custom tiles with info inside as shown in images below. There are quite a few variations of what text is displayed in the tiles, but the overall sizes and such are the same. Problem here is that as my browser window size shrinks, these tiles get all wacky where text disappears or is thrown out of position. What I want to try and have happen is that as the screen gets smaller, rather than show 4 in a row, it shows 2 at 768px breakpoint and then 1 at minimun of 480px. The images show what is there now.

At full size:

[image]

And then as it shrinks, you can see how it gets messed up:

[image]

I am using Bootstrap to help, but with these, I needed to go beyond. As I said, there are a number of variations and these are created using the templating engine within Angular. Code for html for a few below, the call to template and the template itself. Then showing the CSS.

So what can I do to help with this?

the template cards:

```
<div class="beneTile" ng-if="benefit.planTypeId==2">
  <span ng-show="benefit.isPending"><card template2 ng-model="benefit"></card></span>
  <span ng-show="!benefit.isPending">
    <a style="text-decoration: none" href="#/statement?pid={{benefit.planId}}&bid={{benefit.benefitTypeId}}">
      <card template2 ng-model="benefit"></card>
  </a></span>
</div>
<div class="beneTile" ng-if="benefit.planTypeId==3">
  <span ng-show="benefit.isPending"><card template3 ng-model="benefit"></card></span>
  <span ng-show="!benefit.isPending">
    <a style="text-decoration: none" href="#/statement?pid={{benefit.planId}}&bid={{benefit.benefitTypeId}}">
      <card template3 ng-model="benefit"></card>
    </a>
    </span>
</div>
```

And the templates:

```
<!-- template2.html -->
<script type="text/ng-template" id="template2.html">
    <div class="beneHead T4">
        <p>{{ item.name }}</p>
        <div>
            <span>{{ item.beginDate|date : 'MM/dd/yyyy' }} - </span><span>{{ item.endDate|date : 'MM/dd/yyyy' }}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="beneDetails">
        <div>
            <span class="col-md-6 beneImg"><img src="ppt/assets/beneTiles/HRA.svg"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="beneText">
            <p class="beneDesc">Current Balance</p>
            <p class="beneMoney">{{ item.balance | currency }}</p>
            <p class="beneDesc">Annual Benefit</p>
            <p class="beneMoney">{{ item.annualAmt | currency }}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="beneFooter">
            <p><span class="footerStatic">Last day to incur expenses:</span> <span class="footerDynamic">{{ item.lastIncurDate|date : 'MM/dd/yyyy' }}</span></p>
            <p><span class="footerStatic">Last day to submit claims:</span> <span class="footerDynamic">{{ item.lastSubmitDate|date : 'MM/dd/yyyy' }}</span></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>

<!-- template3.html -->
<script type="text/ng-template" id="template3.html">
    <div class="beneHead">
        <p>{{ item.name }}</p>
        <div>
            <span>{{ item.beginDate|date : 'MM/dd/yyyy' }} - </span><span>{{ item.endDate|date : 'MM/dd/yyyy' }}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="beneDetails">
        <div>
            <span class="col-md-6 beneImg"><img src="ppt/assets/beneTiles/Parking.svg"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="beneText">
            <p class="beneDesc">Current Balance</p>
            <p class="beneMoney">{{ item.balance | currency }}</p>
            <p class="beneDesc">Annual Election</p>
            <p class="beneMoney">{{ item.annualAmt | currency }}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="beneFooter">
            <p><span class="footerStatic">Last day to incur expenses:</span> <span span class="footerDynamic">{{ item.lastIncurDate|date : 'MM/dd/yyyy' }}</span></p>
            <p><span class="footerStatic">Last day to submit claims:</span> <span span class="footerDynamic">{{ item.lastSubmitDate|date : 'MM/dd/yyyy' }}</span></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

And now the CSS for it all:

```
.beneTile {
    height: 245px;
    width: 245;
    border: 1px solid #999999;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .beneTile {
        height: 245px;
        width: 245px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .beneTile {
        height: 245px;
        width: 100%;
    }
}

.beneTile:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.beneHead {
    background-color: #8a8c8e;
    height: 90px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.beneHead > p {
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', 'sans-serif';
}

.beneHead > div > span {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', 'sans-serif';
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.T1 {
    background-color: #8a8c8e;
}

.T1:hover {
    background-color: #5a5b5d;
}

.T2 {
    background-color: #ab2328;
}

.T2:hover {
    background-color: #68070b;
}

.T3 {
    background-color: #2dccd3;
}

.T3:hover {
    background-color: #24a4a9;
}

.T4 {
    background-color: #ffb500;
}

.T4:hover {
    background-color: #fc9a26;
}

.beneHead > p {
    margin: 0px;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.beneHead span {
    font-size: 14px;
}

.beneDetails {
    color: #000000;
    height: 155px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

.beneDetails > div> span > img {
    height: 110px;
    width: 120px;
}

.beneText {
    margin: 0;
}

.beneDesc {
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: right;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 18px;
}

.beneMoney {
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #ab2328;
    text-align: right;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    margin: 0;
}

.beneFooter > p, .beneFooter > span {
    font-size: 12px;
    clear: both;
    line-height: 18px;
}

.beneFooter.footerStatic span {
    text-align: left;
}

.beneFooter span.footerDynamic  {
    text-align: right;
    float: right;
}

.beneFooter p span {
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 11px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

I realize a long post and hopefully I provided enough to understand what I have and where I am trying to go. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: you may want to try and reproduce this in a sandbox like jsfiddle, and narrow it down a little... indeed it's a little too long, so chances are you may not get (good) responses, though you may get lucky...

Answer (score 0):

You have fixed `height` here :

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .beneTile {
        height: 245px;
        width: 245px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .beneTile {
        height: 245px;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Try to use `height: auto;` instead and it should be good.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but that does not keep the text content inside of the tile. It helps a little with size, but the text still gets missing similar to what you see in the second image.

Comment: Can you reproduce the example in a JSFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/) so I can help you better ?